# Process job using workers while client waits and return response when complete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job, resque, sidekiq

I'm building an API using Rails where requests come in and they need to be executed by a cluster of workers running on a different server (these workers call remote APIs and parse the data, etc...). I'm going to be using Sidekiq or Resque to handle the queueing/processing of that.

My issue is the client needs to wait while this is happening and the controller needs to return the response to the client once it's complete. How would I handle this in the controller? We're using a redis backend, so I was thinking something along the lines of subscribing to a pub/sub channel and waiting for the worker to publish a status message. The controller would wait for a set time period and then return a 'check back later' response to the client if it doesn't receive a message in time. What would be the best way to implement that, or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 3):

**Do not make your clients wait!** There are a lot of issues if you make the controller block for a long running job:

- Other programs may assume the request timed out (proxies, browsers, scripts, etc.)
- It makes your API endpoints become a source for denial of service
- It requires you to put more engineering work into web servers (since a rails process can't handle another web request while it's handling the blocking call)

Part of the reason of using Sidekiq or Resque is the avoid controllers that do heavily lifting during the http request.

Instead, **background jobs should report their status to the database**. Then web server should query and return to the client the latest status from the database.

If clients need more immediate feedback, you can:

- make clients constantly poll
- post request to the client (if the API consumer is another webserver)
- use another protocol mechanism (eg - websockets).

Comment: I understand what you're saying but unfortunately that isn't possible for our use case. We aren't doing any heavy data processing, we are basically formatting information, passing it along to another API and returning the response. The client expects a response, and cannot poll. The reason for the background workers is so that the API servers aren't doing the backend work.

Comment: The job should take ~2-3 seconds to run.

Comment: These aren't APIs on the internet I presume? What was wrong with making the api servers do the work and just have more servers?